# Strange error when attaching PDF to email

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to attach a PDF file to an email like this:

```
def send_email(gmail, password, post_description, 
               reply_email, attachment_path, email_body_path):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    with open(email_body_path) as f:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(f.read()))

    if attachment_path != None:
        with open(attachment_path, 'rb') as f:
            msg.attach(MIMEApplication(
                f.read(),
                Content_Disposition='attachment, filename="%s"' % basename(f)))
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    smtp.login(gmail, password)
    smtp.sendmail(gmail, 'address@gmail.com', msg.as_string()
```

The PDF is attached and has the correct title, but the contents are always "ECO" and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

See [`email` examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) on how to make attachments correctly:

```
outer = MIMEMultipart()
<...>
fp = open(path, 'rb')

msg = MIMEAplication(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype) #or another appropriate subclass
                                                  #some subclasses have additional parameters
<or>
msg = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
msg.set_payload(fp.read())
encoders.encode_base64(msg)

msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
outer.attach(msg)
```

To add text to the message, you need to attach a `MIMEText` as well as the PDF as per [`multipart/alternative` example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5) (do not forget to specify encoding if it's not the RFC-dictated default, `iso-8859-1`):

```
part = MIMEText(<text>, _charset='<charset>')
outer.attach(part)
```

So, you were doing everything correctly except forming the `MIMEApplication`. `MIMEBase.__init__` source code shows that extra parameters on the constructor call all go into the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: This works, but it attaches the PDF as the body of the message. I need to add text to the body of the email as well, but I can't figure that out